# Does Spring allow use variable as name of resources?

Tags: spring, variables, javabeans

In main file I use tag import for include another xml file with bean definitions. Is possible to use variable as name/path of resource? E.g.

```
<import resource="${custom_beans.xml}"/>
```

?
Thanks.

Comment: yes, I tried and doesn't work. So I don't know if I have made an error or it is principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not, because the import must been resolved before the varaibles are available.